# How can I format python data frame hyperlinks so I can correctly open them with web browser?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to open url links that are located in pandas dataframe column, but I get an error every time I try to open one of them whether they are links to pdfs or to some webpage.

This is my code so far:

```
url = filtrado.iloc[[0]]['Bases reguladoras']

print(url)

webbrowser.get('safari').open_new(url)
```

I get this error (translated from Spanish): "Safari can't open specified address because the first part of it is not valid".

This is one of the urls I'm trying to open: "http://www.bocm.es/boletin/CM_Orden_BOCM/2018/08/09/BOCM-20180809-15.PDF"

When I open the link directly:

```
webbrowser.get('safari').open_new("http://www.bocm.es/boletin/CM_Orden_BOCM/2018/08/09/BOCM-20180809-15.PDF")
```

It works fine so I guess the dataframe is parsing the string someway I can't use it a valid address.

Actually, when trying to download the content with 'requests' library:

```
myfile = requests.get(url)
open('./Prueba_bocm.pdf', 'wb').write(myfile.content)
```

I get the error: " No connection adapters were found for "22    b'http://www.bocm.es/boletin/CM_Orden_BOCM/2018/08/09/BOCM-20180809-15.PDF'\nName: Bases reguladoras, dtype: bytes576" "

Answer (score 0):

Try `filtrado['Bases reguladoras'].iloc[0]` instead of `filtrado.iloc[[0]]['Bases reguladoras']`. The latter returns a `pandas.core.series.Series` while the former is the plain entry.